# Python binary executable envelop

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to protect binary executable with envelop program in python and only allow its execution if certain conditions are met (decrypt the binary and run it)

Standard way to execute a binary is to use subprocess.Popen for example:

```
import subprocess
popen = subprocess.Popen("./binary", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
popen.wait()
output = popen.stdout.read()
print(output)
```

However I don't think this would work in my case as that would require me to decrypt the binary and then execute decrypted file (and potentially expose it)

So I think of decrypting and executing binary data loaded into variable though I don't see the way to run a binary data loaded into variable (through subprocess)

Any suggestions as there might be a better ways that I am not aware?

Comment: how do you plan to decrypt the [encrypted] binary file without exposing the key/decryption mechanism in the envelope script? Could you offer the functionality as web service/api?

Comment: Rough idea is to get encryption key (AES/ Salsa20) from the API service and I thought of packaging both envelope program + 3rd party encrypted binary app together into binary envelope using sth like pyoxidizer.

Comment: actually it looks like golang (and go:embed / go-memexec) are better tools for this task